# Where can I find shapefiles for the ecoregion map of the US?

Tags: data, united-states

I want to find a shapefile for the map at the bottom of

https://www.epa.gov/eco-research/ecoregions

I would want to create a map showing some data for the 10 forest ecoregions.

Answer (score 1):

**Click on the Map**

download the zip file

example:
ftp://ftp.epa.gov/wed/ecoregions/reg8/

**reg8_eco_l4.zip**

unzip the file

[image]

reg_eco_l4.dbf (data/attribution file)

reg_eco_l4.shx (index file)

reg_eco_l4.shp (geometry)

reg_eco_l4.prj (projection file)

other files  are not so important unless using ESRI products..

Comment: I knew that I could get the shapefile for each region. I wanted to get a shapefile for the overall map, with information for all the regions.

Comment: Merge and Dissolve can be applied - note: Please note: Web pages for Level IV Ecoregions are under construction. If you do not find a link to a state that
has been completed, maps and GIS data are available on the Ecoregion FTP site and a web site will be
available shortly.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? How do I do merge in R? I have calculated the mean of each region. I want to map the means.

Comment: The Merge and Dissolve that @Mapperz was talking about would be performed in your GIS Software of choice, either QGIS or ArcGIS.  You would download the shapefiles for the various regions, then merge the shapefiles into a single shapefile that contains polygons, and thus, data for each region.  Since these have unique identifiers, the data can then be used in R for any statistical processing, ex. Means.  This can be linked back to the shapefile and then symbolized in the GIS software.